# How to print output with linebreakers from command line

Tags: command-line, printing, output, cat

When I want to print an output like this

```
./myScript (prints some lines)
```

or

```
cat myFile
```

I want the output to show with linebreakers `,` for example each line will include not more than 100 chars.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffffff
vbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbf
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

there is something I can add to the command line to get this result ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` if you want the line terminator as `,`.

```
$ cat myfile
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffffffvbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

```
$ sed -r 's/.{50}/&,\n/g' myfile
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffffffvbbb,
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbfaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

`fold` is another utility but won't add a `,` at the end

```
$ fold -w50 myfile
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaffffffvbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbfaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```